# How to force visual studio follow ISO C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, gcc

I've happily written C++ project in Visual Studio 2013. I did not use any non-standard extension **explicitly**, though when I moved to GCC 4.8 in Ubuntu I've received many errors, because I used non-standard extensions **implicitly**. For example:

```
#include <vector>

template<class T>
class A
{
    public:
    using MyVector = std::vector<T>;
};

template<class T>
class B : public A<T>
{
    MyVector vec;
};
```

This code(here is [link](http://cpp.sh/3x5mo)) is legal with default settings of VS2013, though in GCC: `error: 'MyVector' has not been defined`, and it is conformant with ISO.

So my question is: if I'm 100% sure, that my code should be ISO-conformant, can I force visual studio to follow ISO C++ standard **strictly**?

Comment: Did you compile with `-std=c++11`?

Comment: Yes, of course. I assume, that if I compiled without c++11, I've received different error about bad syntax.

Comment: `1>source.cpp(9): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'template' 1>source.cpp(14): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'end of file'`

Comment: Apart from the fact you are missing a ';' at the end of both class declarations, shouldn't the 'MyVector' declaration be hidden to derived classes because of the implicit private scope?

Comment: Did you try to compile with options [`/Za` and `/Zc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe.aspx)?

Comment: @SébastienCôté No. It does work as stated above for MSVC and also works with gcc when using `typename A<T>::MyVector vec;`. Look at the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643035/propagating-typedef-from-based-to-derived-class-for-template

Comment: @SimonKraemer Yes, it works because explicit lookup is not performed in gcc according to standard, though performed in VS.

Comment: @SébastienCôté Oh, thank you, I've edited question

Comment: @nwp `/Za` seems to do the trick: `main.cpp(13): error C3646: 'vec': unknown override specifier
main.cpp(14): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'B<T>' being compiled
main.cpp(13): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`

Comment: @DoctorMoisha I was referring to the "implicit private scope" Sébastien mentioned

Comment: You can use Clang as a compiler in MSVS now.

Comment: There are different problems with using `/Za`, like [Windows system headers not compiling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489326/za-compiler-directive-does-not-compile-system-headers-in-vs2010).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about old visual studio feature

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be work undergoing in this direction by MS recently:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/permissive-switch/

You can try it, maybe it will solve problem at least partially.