# C++ Issues with windows.h, Illegal declaration of anonymous 'struct' in vs17

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, header-files

When the following code is compiled I get these errors:

```
Error C2467 illegal declaration of anonymous 'struct'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winnt.h 12723
Error C2133 '_IMAGE_POLICY_METADATA::Policies': unknown size
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winnt.h 20801
Error C2467 illegal declaration of anonymous 'struct'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winioctl.h 4327
```

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Timer!\n Enter a number of seconds: \n";
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(n*1000));
    std::cout << "Timer is up";
    std::cout << '\a';
    return 0;
}
```

These errors do not occur when `windows.h` is removed, as I am somewhat new I could be making a basic mistake however a lot of tutorials use it and it simply does not want to work. I have used a very basic snippet of code so that it is easier to determine whether it is a mistake on my behalf or an error somewhere else.

Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019 16.2.5

Comment: The Windows headers cannot be compiled without also enabling language extensions. They are enabled by default, make sure you didn't disable them.

Comment: try to move #include<windows.h> to the first line

Comment: So the disable language extensions should be set to false?

Comment: moving #include<windows.h> had no effect

Comment: @TobyHogg Yes. To use `<windows.h>` you need to have "disable language extensions" as "false". If this fixes the problem, this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489326/za-compiler-directive-does-not-compile-system-headers-in-vs2010

Comment: Disable language extensions is set as 'No'

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I am unsure as to how this is a duplicate as the answers to the linked question do not seem to have an effect on this issue, my thinking would be an error in visual studio perhaps but i would argue this issue is not a duplicate due to the fact that /Za is not in use

Comment: @TobyHogg I was mistaken. I thought the answer below was posted by you, confirming that /Za was in use. Since that is not the case I've reopened the question.

Answer (score 4):

As @FrançoisAndrieux mentions in the comments, the `windows.h` header requires not enabling the "Disable Language Extensions" option under C/C++ -> Language (switch `/Za`).

However, if you are only looking to compile simple code that does not require `windows.h`, simply remove it. You can write:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Timer!\n Enter a number of seconds: \n";
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(n*1000));
    std::cout << "Timer is up\a";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that ``/Za`` is a particularly old switch. It was intended to conform to "ANSI" standards several decades ago, and is therefore not really useful anymore. VS 2019 does support the ``/permissive-`` switch which is a more modern approach to improving portability and modern Windows SDK headers work with it enabled. See [this Visual C++ blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/permissive-switch/).

Comment: Disable language extensions is set to 'No', i was planning to use windows.h further on but when adding it and testing the error occurred.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Indeed. I hope at some point the VS team changes the description for the option in the IDE, since it keeps making newcomers fall into it... (or perhaps move it into Advanced instead).

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Has anything changed now that Microsoft will support C standards? Thank you!

Comment: ``/Za`` is still unchanged and produces the same warnings as the original question. If you use ``/std:c11`` or ``/std:c17`` with VS 2019 16.8, it produces no errors. You can also add ``/permissive-`` as well. See [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c11-and-c17-standard-support-arriving-in-msvc/).

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Thanks for the update & the link, Chuck.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the two error descriptions are related to that switch which is as @Acorn said. The link below is Microsoft's official document. If you can't solve your problem in this way. Maybe you need to consider using VS tool to repair your environment.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2467?view=vs-2015
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2133?view=vs-2015